# IEnumerable vs List in a cshtml file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

I wanted to ask let say i have a cshtml code

```
@model List<Product>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
```

- 
- 
- 

and it goes like this with no problem. My question is i can write `IEnumerable<Product>` instead of `List<Product>` in both situations my program works, so which should i prefer and why?

Comment: If all you want to do is iterate over the model then use `IEnumerable<T>` as it is more generic and would allow the code behind to change and pass something else other than `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEnumerable is a more generic type than ICollection, IList and List.

If you are not using any method like "AddRange", which is just for List, or "Add", which is just for IList (and List) but you just need to loop over the collection with a foreach you should prefer IEnumerable.

This allows you to use any implementation of IEnumerable, such as List or HashSet:

```
public ActionResult MyAction() {
    List<Product> list = GetProducts();
    return View(list); //works in both cases (IEnumerable and List)
}

public ActionResult MyAction() {
    HashSet<Product> list = GetProducts();
    return View(list); //does not work if you declare the cshtml Model as List
}

public ActionResult MyAction() {
    IEnumerable<Product> products = GetProducts();
    return View(products); // works only if you declare the Model as IEnumerable
}
```

That said, if you declare the model as IEnumerable of Product you don't have to worry about the implementation that will be used